# Checking if a string is empty or null in Java

Tags: java

I'm parsing HTML data.  The `String` may be `null` or empty, when the word to parse does not match.

So, I wrote it like this:

```
if(string.equals(null) || string.equals("")){
    Log.d("iftrue", "seem to be true");
}else{
    Log.d("iffalse", "seem to be false");
}
```

When I delete `String.equals("")`, it does not work correctly.

I thought `String.equals("")` wasn't correct.

How can I best check for an empty `String`?

Comment: This question is much better than its duplicate. More concise, better wording.

Comment: Not to mention it shows as the top result on Google ☺

Comment: Since Java 11 you can use isBlank() methid of String class which will check for both empty string or string consist of only white spaces. so you can do something like (str != null && !str.isBlank()), Thanks

Comment: `if (string == null || string.isEmpty("")) {` would be the correct null check and improved empty string check; `isBlank` would also allow whitespace (tabs, spaces). Mind: `null.equals(...)` gives a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 623):

Correct way to check for null or empty or string containing only spaces is like this:

```
if(str != null && !str.trim().isEmpty()) { /* do your stuffs here */ }
```

Comment: OK to use != for null, but *never* for ""

Comment: Just FYI, IsEmpty() does not return true for a string containing only spaces.

Comment: The negation of this answer is exactly how Guava's [Strings.isNullOrEmpty](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Strings.html#isNullOrEmpty-java.lang.String-) is implemented.

Comment: @HonzaKalfus *"Calling isEmpty() returns true for string containing whitespace character"* - That is not true! "     ".isEmpty() returns **false**

Comment: @HonzaKalfus That's not true. String.isEmpty() checks if String.length == 0 and " " has a length of 1.

Comment: first check for null  then empty string, order is important , otherwise it will throw null pointer exception. @Pradeep add this line

Comment: fyi  `if(!"".equals(str))`, is inelegant but works without Utils class, but I prefer  `StringUtils.isEmpty()` for clarity

Comment: @bluelurker , @PradeepSimha To catch _"a string containing only spaces"_, You could add `trim()` to the if-condition. i.e `if (theItem != null && !theItem.trim().isEmpty()) {}`

Comment: java srouce: public boolean isEmpty() {
        return this.value.length == 0;
    }

Comment: Since Java 11, ```str.trim().isEmpty()``` can be replaced with ```str.isBlank()```

Answer (score 422):

You can leverage Apache Commons [`StringUtils.isEmpty(str)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence)), which checks for empty strings and handles `null` gracefully.

Example:

```
System.out.println(StringUtils.isEmpty("")); // true
System.out.println(StringUtils.isEmpty(null)); // true
```

Google Guava also provides a similar, probably easier-to-read method:  [`Strings.isNullOrEmpty(str)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Strings.html#isNullOrEmpty(java.lang.String)).

Example:

```
System.out.println(Strings.isNullOrEmpty("")); // true
System.out.println(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(null)); // true
```

Comment: As a side note, the method name is a bit misleading. Intuitively `isEmpty(null)` would return false as it's not an empty string.

Comment: Note,  isEmpty() just uses "return cs == null || cs.length() == 0;"  Also, since commons.lang 2.0, isEmpty() no longer trims the String.  So, StringUtils.isEmpty(" ") returns false - but StringUtils.isBlank("  ") returns true.

Comment: @SteveKuo   println(org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.isEmpty(null)); // true
It returns TRUE only...

Answer (score 117):

You can use Apache commons-lang

`StringUtils.isEmpty(String str)`  - Checks if a String is empty ("") or null.

or

`StringUtils.isBlank(String str)`  - Checks if a String is whitespace, empty ("") or null.

the latter considers a String which consists of spaces or special characters eg " " empty too. See java.lang.Character.isWhitespace API

Comment: For non-Java users like myself; be sure to include `import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;` and ensure your package manager has it marked as a dependency.

Comment: @TJBiddle. Great tip! I had to laugh at "for non-Java users" because I've been programming Android for years (in Java), through Eclipse and AndroidStudio, and still needed this tip. I never understood that gradle, or whatever preceeded it, was a Java "package manager". I write the Java code which should work, and then start fixing dependency problems (if any) with the assistance of StackOverflow :). This time round, after years of "ouches", I pre-empted it and put the "dependency in the package manager", before writing the code. (as below)

Comment: To add the apache package, put `dependencies { implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.7' }` in `build.gradle (Module app)`. If there is already a `dependencies` block then just insert a new line with this dependency. This is the latest recommended version, as of Feb '20 (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55567755/1541141). Then clean and/or sync your project.

Answer (score 43):

```
import com.google.common.base.Strings;

if(!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(String str)) {
   // Do your stuff here 
}
```

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'Strings'

Comment: Strings (cf. answer from hari) is from Guava (com.google.common.base.Strings).

Comment: And all for the low low cost of adding 2.7 MB to your build.

Comment: Oh, come on, add lib to check null or empty, definitly not the case

Answer (score 38):

This way you check if the string is not null and not empty, also considering the empty spaces:

```
boolean isEmpty = str == null || str.trim().length() == 0;
if (isEmpty) {
    // handle the validation
}
```

Comment: It should be `str.trim().isEmpty()` for simplicity.

Comment: @DavidS If you remove `str == null` from code and str variable is 'null', then it will throw 'NullPointerException'.

Comment: Yes, you're right @AlfazJikani. I was saying to replace `str.trim().length() == 0` with `str.trim().isEmpty()`, not remove the null check.

Comment: @DavidS, My bad! I agree with you.