# How to add org.apache.commons.lang3 to AndroidStudio with gradle

Tags: android, apache, gradle, stringescapeutils

Due to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994331/java-how-to-decode-html-character-entities-in-java-like-httputility-htmldecode)
I want to use class `StringEscapeUntils` in package `org.apache.commons.lang3`.

But when I try to import `Apache` lib by add line `compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.0'` to `build.grade` file then can not import the class above.

Is there any one can help me how to import above one to my project via gradle (not by download .jar and put them into project folder).

Answer (score 191, accepted):

**Edited 07.12.2018:**

I think dependency for `StringUtils` you are using is not proper.

Please add below dependency to gradle and Sync project and import your class.

```
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6'
```

This on is using deprecated task (but should still works):

<s>compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5'</s>

**Edit:**

As OoDeLally mentioned in a comment,

Above mentioned version is deprecated,
Please use below dependency:

```
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.9'
```

**Edit 2:**

deprecated as for July 2019. Use [stackoverflow.com/a/55567755/1541141](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55567755/1541141) instead

Thanks @OoDeLally!

Comment: org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5 is out as of Oct 2016

Comment: Don't use this lib. By using this lib, While uploading apk to Google play store, It will show 0 supported devices. Instead use compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'. it works.

Comment: It has changed to `org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.4` now

Comment: latest one is `implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9'
`

Comment: deprecated as for July 2019. Use https://stackoverflow.com/a/55567755/1541141 instead.

Answer (score 8):

for StringUtils you need to add in **app.gradle**

```
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.7'
```

Comment: Should this now get added to app/build.gradle instead?

Answer (score 7):

`StringEscapeUtils` class moved to `org.apache.commons:commons-text`. package.

For `StringEscapeUtils` you need to add `'org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.6'` dependency.

Answer (score 0):

After adding

```
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.7'
```

in **build.gradle** as mentioned above, some of you might be facing the following exception on rebuild:

```
Invoke-customs are only supported starting with android 0 --min-api 26
```

In this case, just add the follwing in your build.gradle as well:

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

**NOTE:**

The example above is for Java 8. For those who are on Java 7, simply replace 1_8 by 1_7.