# Best way for comparing two strings and checking for null value

Tags: java

I have following code:

```
String tmpTotalCost = "";    
tmpTotalCost = request.getParameter("TotalCost");

if(tmpTotalCost == null) 
    tmpTotalCost = "";
if(tmpTotalCost == "") 
    tmpTotalCost = "0.00";
```

What would be the best way to check if `tmpTotalCost` is null or empty?
I would always write a code that would finish the job, but I never thought about performance.

Comment: Well, first `== ""` wouldn't necessarily get the job done.

Comment: I'm out of votes. Someone: [Java, check whether a string is not null and not empty?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598770/java-check-whether-a-string-is-not-null-and-not-empty)

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14721397/checking-if-a-string-is-empty-or-null-in-java

Comment: check str.length() != 0

Comment: @PrashantSrivastav There is an `isEmpty()` method for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use StringUtils from Apache Commons Lang library. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html