# NullPointerException in imagepath

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have a String imagepath which has path of the selected image. If user selects image i have to upload it on sever. I want to check wheter imagepath is null. I have tried this but it give `NullPointerException`.

This is my code.

```
public String imagepath = null;
public String imagepath1 = null;
```

and I am checking if it is null as:

```
   Log.e("imagepath",""+imagepath);
            Log.e("imagepath1", ""+imagepath1);

            if (imagepath.equals(null)){
                Log.e("no image path","dfdsfdsfdsfdsfdf");

            }
            else {
                uploadFile(imagepath);
            }

            if (imagepath1.equals(null)){
                Log.e("no imagepath1 path","imagepath1");

            }
            else {
                uploadFile2(imagepath);
            }
```

If I do not select any image, it shows `NullPointerException`. Please help me. What is wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 if(imagepath != null && imagepath.isEmpty()) { /* do your stuffs here */ }
```

for more reference check this:

[Checking if a string is empty or null in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14721397/checking-if-a-string-is-empty-or-null-in-java)

more specific way to check if a string is null or not is using `TextUtils`:

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(imagepath )) {
    Log.d(TAG, "imagepath is empty or null!");
}
```

Comment: `TextUtils.isEmpty` will do that for you

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, you are right..

Answer (score 1):

You should use try catch to handle this exception because NullPointerException occurs when object not have any value or not defined and here you are **not selecting any image** that's why NullPointerExcepion occured [Reference for nullPointerException](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)

Answer (score 0):

See first that the two strings are not null before proceeding. Try this:

```
if(imagepath!=null) {

    //Do your stuff
    uploadfile(imagepath);

} else {
    // Handle the exception
}
if(imagepath1!=null) {

    //Do your stuff
    uploadfile(imagepath1);

} else {
    // Handle the exception
}
```