# Java String is getting replaced with case sensitivity

Tags: java, string

I have a string where I have to replace it with a substring. For eg, "Servicing" is the word. I have a substring as "servi". Now, i need to check if "Servicing" has "servi". If yes, then i need to replace it with "servicing". When i try to replace, it is getting displayed as "servi". But the expected output is "Servicing"Can you please help me in resolving this ? Please find the code below.

```
String stringValue = "Servicing";
if (stringValue != null && stringValue != "") {
    i = stringValue.toLowerCase().indexOf("servi", i+1);
    if(i>=0){
        newData = stringValue .replaceAll("(?i)"+"servi", "<mark>"+"servi"+"</mark>");
        System.out.println(newData); // Case sensitive should remain same as String. Not as substring.
        i = -1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How about using a regexp with some capture?

Comment: What is `i`?  We need to see all the relevant code.

Comment: i is to ignore case sensitive

Comment: You realize that `toLowerCase` does not change the value of `stringValue`, right?

Comment: I don't understand: *"Servicing" is the word* ... *the expected output is "Servicing"*.

Comment: @Kutty I meant the var `i`, not the regex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
String stringValue = "Servicing";
if (stringValue != null && !stringValue.isEmpty()) {
     String newData = stringValue.replaceAll("(?i)servi", "<mark>$0</mark>");
     System.out.println(newData);
}
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/ky4cAw)

**Details**:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive inline modifier
- `servi` - a literal char sequence
- `$0` - a backreference to the whole match value. It makes sure you insert the `servi` with the matched case (no need to hardcode it inside the replacement as in the original code).

Comment: Really `stringValue != ""` ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14721418/982149 I tend to correct this, wherever I see it. No matter if part of the question or not. But I see why this wasn't your concern.

Comment: @Fildor: Good job, I also have my own "pet peeves".

Comment: This works awesome for case sensitive. But i am getting the output as "<mark>Servicing</mark>". The expected output should be "<mark>Serv</mark>icing"

Comment: Remove `\\w*` then, I thought you wanted to wrap the *whole word* starting with `servi`.